# Prove that there exist infinitely many pairs $(m,n)$ such that $m<n, \gcd(m,n)=1$, and $\sigma(n)=\sigma(m)$

Tags: number-theory

Here, $\sigma(x)=\sum_{d|x} d$

N that $\sigma(6)=\sigma(11)$ and $\sigma(17)=\sigma(10)$, so maybe I can set $n=p$ be an odd prime and use the multiplicative property of $\sigma$ to construct $m<p$.  Since $m<p$ I only need to worry about constructing $m$. In particular let $p+1=ab$ and find $\sigma(k)=a$, $\sigma(m)=b$, $\gcd(k,m)=1$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried the following but then got stuck.

Comment: That's not something you can always do. Say, $\sigma(29)=30$, now good luck constructing $m<p$ with the same sum of divisors.

Comment: $p=13$ fails too

Comment: Let $g(x)$ be the number of $a<b\le x$ such that $\sigma(a)=\sigma(b)$ and $(a,b)=1$. It is solved in here: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/btran10.pdf that $g(x)\ge c x^{1.4}$ for some positive $c$. Thus, there infinitely many such $m, n$ in your question.